# Remove newlines and spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

How can I remove newline between `<table> .... </table>` and add \n after each

ex:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="450" class="descriptiontable"><tr>
<td width="50%" valign="top">
<span class="displayb">Model Procesor:</span> Intel Celeron<br><span class="displayb">Frecventa procesor (MHz):</span> 2660<br><span class="displayb">Placa Video:</span> Intel Extreme Graphics 2<br><span class="displayb">Retea integrata:</span> 10/100Mbps, RJ-45<br><span class="displayb">Chipset:</span> Intel 845G<br>
</td>
<td width="50%" valign="top">
<span class="displayb">Capacitate RAM (MB):</span> 512<br><span class="displayb">Tip RAM:</span> DDR<br>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

and become :

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="450" class="descriptiontable"><tr><td width="50%" valign="top"><span class="displayb">Model Procesor:</span> Intel Celeron<br><span class="displayb">Frecventa procesor (MHz):</span> 2660<br><span class="displayb">Placa Video:</span> Intel Extreme Graphics 2<br><span class="displayb">Retea integrata:</span> 10/100Mbps, RJ-45<br><span class="displayb">Chipset:</span> Intel 845G<br></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><span class="displayb">Capacitate RAM (MB):</span> 512<br><span class="displayb">Tip RAM:</span> DDR<br></td></tr></table>\n
```

s.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove that whitespace?  Do you imagine that it is a performance improvement of some kind?  I suggest that it will not have any noticeable effect.  If you're trying to speed things up, measure where your time goes first.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean that you have a complete HTML file/string and only want to remove the linebreaks inside tables.

You should probably use a DOM parser to find the corresponding parts of your HTML, but this makeshift regex solution might work just fine for you:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+(?=(?:(?!<table).)*</table>)~is', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~</table>~i', "$0\n", $str);
```

If you want to add the `\n` only if it was not there already, you could go with this as the second replacement:

```
$str = preg_replace('~</table>(?!\n)~i', "$0\n", $str);
```

This matches (system independently) all line breaks, **if** they are followed by `</table>` without `<table` somewhere in between. This will, of course, cause problems with nested tables and similar things. Which is why you should use a DOM parser.

Comment: Thank you for the regex and the tip. I know what i need to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $string);
```

This removes multiple spaces and newlines.

At the end, you just have to add "\n" to the result:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $string) . "\n";
```

This should do it.

Comment: but this is not betwen those to tags html <table> </table> and add a \n @ the end of </table>

Comment: wouldn't this code only work on Windows-style line endings, where a line break has two characters?

Comment: Well, I assumed that you have your table markup in a `$string` on the server side.

Comment: i have linux on webhost. I have more rows like that in ex and i want to do 1 for each row to make an csv.

Comment: so what's your remaining problem?

Comment: he wants to replace newline between table not everything

Answer (score 0):

I find a way, i forget to post it

```
$content = str_replace('</table',"</table>\n",str_replace("\n","",$str));
```